# AngularJS convert array of strings into array of float

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, floating-point

guys! I have a problem converting an array of strings into floats. If i use map(parseFloat) I get int numbers. Is there a problem with the commas in 40,78, that is why I get 40 when I use the parseFloat function ?

This is the array I want to convert:

```
[["40,78","6,27","0,00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"35,87",null,null]];
```

I want to convert it into this:

```
[[40.78,6.27,0.00,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,35.87,null,null]];
```

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: But, if you do that and when you check the array length, it will return only `1`.

Answer (score 2):

It's as you say. `parseFloat()` considers as float numbers only strings with `.` character, not `,`. Also it returns `NaN` for `null` values:

```js
var arr = ["40,78","6,27","0,00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"35,87",null,null];
    
var res = arr.map(function(val) {
  return val ? parseFloat(val.replace(',', '.')) : null;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.array= ["40,78","6,27","0,00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"35,87",null,null]
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.array.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.array[i] !== null) {
            $scope.array[i] = parseFloat($scope.array[i].replace(',','.'))
      }
    }
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/p2kpeptq/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["40,78","6,27","0,00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"35,87",null,null];
arr.map(function(v) {
  return v === null ? v : parseFloat(v.replace(",", "."));
});
```

In your case you have a double array. Depends on your use case if you do an additional `.map` call or handle the outer array in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You have '40,78' comma separated strings, for parsing to float you need to have dot separated strings f.e: '40.78' and map(parseFloat) would work correctly.